# How it work of this javascript "var ApplicationConfig = {"

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

How is working in "`var ApplicationConfig = {" and " ApplicationForm: { submitUrl: validateFieldUrl:processWindowUrl:rejectedUrl:`"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ApplicationConfig = {
        mobile: false,
        messages: {"account_number_format_error":"4-30 digits are needed in the field &quot;Account Number&quot;"},
        ApplicationForm: {
            submitUrl: 'application-submit.php',
            validateFieldUrl: 'application-validate-field.php',
            processWindowUrl: 'application-process.php',
            rejectedUrl: 'page-reject.php'
        },
        multipartTextfieldContainer: '.dev-form-multipart-text-field',
        autocomplete: {
            url: 'application-autocomplete.php'
        },
        abTestValues: {"igf_frm_small":"1"}    };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? It makes no sense to me...

Comment: thats just a object carrying settings for other libs to use. what are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

That is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals).

It is a way of constructing a basic object while defining properties and values at the same time.

```
var foo = { bar: baz; };
```

is equivalent to:

```
var foo = new Object();
foo.bar = baz;
```